# How to retrieve HiveList from Flutter Hive

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I need help with retrieving data from Flutter Hive using HiveList; I get the error below:

> HiveError: To use this list, you have to open the box " " first.
> E/flutter ( 3001): #0 HiveListImpl.box"

I am trying to implement Hive relation from [this sample](https://www.reddit.com/r/FlutterDev/comments/ee5gti/hive_v120_supports_relationships_inheritance_and/) and no sample for retrieve data yet.

edited the code to open Box for Header and Details. still no chance to load data.

```dart
static Future<List<SaleTicket>> getAllSaleTickets() async {

  final _saleTicketBox = await Hive.box<SaleTicket>(_hive.SALE_TICKET_BOX);
  final _saleTicketHeaderBox = await Hive.box<SaleTicketHeader>(_hive.SALE_TICKET_COL_BOX);

  final _saleTicketHeader = (_saleTicketBox.isEmpty || _saleTicketBox.values.isEmpty)
    ? SaleTicketHeader()
    : _saleTicketHeaderBox.values.firstWhere((t) => t.id=1);

    _saleTicketHeader.saleTickets = HiveList(_saleTicketBox); // open ticket box
    return _saleTicketHeader.saleTickets.toList();
}
```

Comment: As it says in the error, you need to open the box. You probably miss that. Can you share some code?

Comment: update my question with some code and still no clues :)
anyway this Hive relation features is still in experimental.

Answer (score 1):

It's a confusing error message, but it should be because you have to specify the generic type in the HiveList, just like you did when you opened.

```
_saleTicketHeader.saleTickets = HiveList<SaleTicket>(_saleTicketBox);
```

So, Hive.box and HiveList have the types dismatched.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to make it work by loop through the HiveList Key. Not sure it is best way ?

```
static Future<List<SaleTicket>> getAllSaleTickets() async {
final _saleTicketBox = await Hive.box<SaleTicket>('sale_ticket_box');
final _saleTicketHeaderBox = await Hive.box<SaleTicketHeader>('sale_ticket_header_box');

final _saleTicketHeader = (_saleTicketHeaderBox.isEmpty || _saleTicketHeaderBox.values.isEmpty) ? SaleTicketHeader() : _saleTicketHeaderBox.values.firstWhere((t) => t.id = 1);
var saleTicketList = <SaleTicket>[];
_saleTicketHeader.saleTickets.**keys.forEach**((key) {
  saleTicketList.add(_saleTicketBox.get(key));
});

  }

  class SaleTicket extends HiveObject{
  @HiveField(0)
  String TicketName;
  ...
  }

  class SaleTicketHeader extends HiveObject{
  @HiveField(0)
  String TicketHeaderName;
  ...
  @HiveField(1)
  HiveList<SaleTicket> saleTickets;
  }
```